# NAT in UTM Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, nat

I use UTM Virtual Machine and want to simulate between 2 VM and 1 host, but I use Mac m1, for this case, I want use UTM to simulate it, whats network mode similiar with NAT in UTM?

Answer (score 0):

but using NAT will not let u communicate with other VMs. U can only connect to the HOST network.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35443162)